# Why do we get the ASCII characters with int i within %c?

Tags: c, for-loop, integer, character, ascii

If you run the following code you will get the ASCII characters, even though we use `int i` within `%c` inside the for loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
    
int main()  
{  
    int i;  
    
    for (i = 0; i <= 255; i++) /*ASCII values ranges from 0-255*/  
    {  
        printf("ASCII value of character %c = %d\n", i, i);  
    }  

    return 0;  
}
```

Could you please advise how is this possible since there are characters inside ASCII?

Comment: Integers smaller than `int` are automatically promoted to `int` when passed to `printf` variadic function. The "character" you are passing is an integer. So when you passed a `char` variable, it was automatically promoted to `int` anyway, and that is the type that `%c` is expecting (so no warning was given). The `%c` differs from the `%d` only in the *way* that the value passed is rendered to the output.

Comment: "there are characters inside ASCII" - no, there are integers. They are converted to visible characters by the output device. Their visual shape (or control function) is what the ASCII table defines.

Comment: @el_noobito Yes, this works great, and is an excellent demonstration of the fact that, in C at least, characters are just small integers.  My question for you is, in what way did you expect it to fail?  Did you expect to get a compiler warning, along the lines of "`format specifies type 'char' but the argument has type 'int'`"?  Or did you expect to get garbage output, like you do it you try something like `printf("%d", 3.14)`?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Yes I expected to fail when I compiled it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every variable in the computer is stored as binary and its value will depend on the type you define. For example, in memory store the value `1010`. If you cast it as `int`, it will print -6, if you cast it as `unsigned int`, it will print 10. Same for int and char. It depends on you

Answer (score 0):

printf() - **Print formatted**
we use format specifiers to specify the format of given variable,
**%d** format specifier to display the value of an integer variable.
**%c** is used to display character
as ASCII values ranges from 0-256 , **%c**  will print the respective character symbol of number in Integer **i**

Comment: Hmmm "as ASCII values ranges from 0-256" --> I suspect you want 0-255.  Note [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) only defines 0-127,